# Where does $product->getData('salable') come from?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1.7

I have a problem with one of the products. For some reason it doesn't display a buy button. I dig into the core and I figured it out that the problem with this value. 
Inside function isSalable() It returns at the step

```
if ($this->hasData('salable')) {
    return $this->getData('salable');
}
```

And it returns 'false', but I don't know why. Other methods like `isAvailable()` or `isInStock()` or `getStatus()` return true. Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5238/146

Comment: Thank you @Marius, I've seen that, but it doesn't help. It's about magento 1. My question about magento2

Comment: I think the code and explanation is very similar to m1. Just the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

`'salable'` set from `Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php`

Check `function isSalable()` from above file.

salable set from isSalable function with line,

```
$this->setData('salable', $object->getIsSalable());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @rakesh-jesadiya. As I told before, I've seen that function, but this function returns before this line, at this line https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1636

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to repeat but to expand upon other answer.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/00fb2aa3e258ab728f8e2fec1e99bc9b5f562221/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1672-L1696

```
    public function isSalable()
    {
        if ($this->_catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (($this->getOrigData('status') != $this->getData('status'))
            || $this->isStockStatusChanged()) {
            $this->unsetData('salable');
        }
        if ($this->hasData('salable')) {
            return $this->getData('salable');
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_is_salable_before', ['product' => $this]);
        $salable = $this->isAvailable();
        $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['product' => $this, 'is_salable' => $salable]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_product_is_salable_after',
            ['product' => $this, 'salable' => $object]
        );
        $this->setData('salable', $object->getIsSalable());
        return $this->getData('salable');
    }
```

Not seeing any different in behavior in 2.1

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1630-L1654

So it's checked.  If exists it returns which is this part `if ($this->hasData('salable')) {`.  If not exist it is set with `$this->setData('salable', $object->getIsSalable());` part after event.

So it can be in a situation where it doesn't return before that line.